# Ruby on Rails: Multiple Smtp port in one action mailer smtp configuration setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Is there any way to use multiple `smtp port` in one `smtp` configuration like

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
:user_name            => "rdas",
:password             => "guru",
:domain               => "stainly.com",
:address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
:port                 => 587 && 1025,
:authentication       => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Why would you use two ports?

Comment: Thank you for showing interrest on my post one will be used for a server called `mailcatcher` server